# Promise not resolving using async and await

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I´m trying to learn about Promises and Async/Await.

Please, understand that I´m new so feel free to contribute with as many suggestions as you want.

The idea is to simulate a connection to a DB or the response from an API endpoint with retrieveUserFromFB() which is going to return a promise.

Then, returnUsernameViaUserid() which is async will invoke retrieveUserFromFB() and resolve the promise. Or that´s what I think.

```js
async function returnUsernameViaUserid(userId) {
  const result = await retrieveUserFromFB();
  return result;
}


function retrieveUserFromFB() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve({user: 'thisistheusername'});
    }, 1000)
  });
}

console.log(returnUsernameViaUserid(1));
```

But the output is always Promise {  }
I will appreciate any help. The userId is just a colorful detail, not functional and I´m not passing it to retrieveUserFromFB(). Just to be clear =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## An `async function` returns a promise

Your issue is that currently, you're trying to log the result of an asynchronous function which is always a `Promise`, to remedy this, place your `console.log` in the `async function`.

Another solution would be to use `.then` on `retrieveUserFromFB` to avoid the `async function` altogether, if you so choose.

```js
async function returnUsernameViaUserid(userId) {
  const result = await retrieveUserFromFB();
  console.log(result);
}


function retrieveUserFromFB() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve({user: 'thisistheusername'});
    }, 1000)
  });
}

returnUsernameViaUserid(1)
```

Comment: or we can `returnUsernameViaUserid(1).then(res => console.log(res))`.